# Is the term Kyrie Eleison Latin or Greek?

Tags: liturgy, greek, phrase, latin

***Kyrie Eleison*** is a term that is used in the Latin Mass of the Catholic Church. However, I've been told that the phrase is entirely Greek and not Latin at all!

So is the phrase Latin or Greek? Is it transliterated from Greek and therefore Latin?

Comment: This kind of question is off topic here. It could be on topic at [hermeneutics.se], but you would need to [edit] it to ask about a specific verse.

Comment: Brother/Sister, the phrase isn't from the bible. It is from Catholic tradition. But you can find kyrie and eleison as separate words in different forms in the original Greek of the New Testament of course. It means "Lord have mercy."

Comment: Math 20:31, it's very much in the bible as is the fullness of the faith in the Catholic Church. Kyrie is the Greek translation. The petition is ancient in origin as it was spoken to Christ as the blind men asked the Lord to see.  @Geoyws, perhaps that request should be made by you.

Comment: I make that request all the time @Marc.
Like I said, it is of separate words, and not of a phrase. "Ἐλέησον ἡμᾶς, κύριε, υἱὸς Δαβίδ"
http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Mat&c=20&t=KJV#s=t_conc_949031

Comment: "Lord Have Mercy"  tradition of the catholic Church.  
"Have Mecry on us oh Lord"  not a tradtion?

Comment: @curiousdannii As part of the Catholic mass, this is definitely on topic here. The fact that the phrase also appears in the Bible does not make it off-topic.

Comment: +1 It took me a while to figure out why this was so different to Miserere Nobis (used during the Communion rite)

Comment: Do where does Constantine come in this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is simply Greek that has been written in Roman letters.

The city of Rome was [essentially bilingual](http://anthrojournal.com/issue/october-2011/article/greek-and-latin-bilingualism-beyond-the-upper-class-in-the-ancient-roman-principate) from around the time of Caesar Augustus until at least the third or fourth century A.D.: the people spoke mostly vulgar Latin or common (Koine) Greek. Greek was the more common language among the poor, who formed the majority of the ranks of the Church at first. The Roman liturgy, therefore, was originally composed in Greek, and was only translated into Latin in the third century, as vulgar Latin gradually became the more common language. (The [*Wikipedia* article on the pre-Tridentine liturgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Tridentine_Mass) has some good sources and information, actually.)

In any case, the *Kyrie* is simply the transliteration in Roman letters of the Greek Κύριε (or Χρίστε), ἐλέησον, “Lord (or Christ), have mercy.” It is all that remains of the original Greek version of the Roman Rite.

Comment: [A more complete article on the subject is available on New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08714a.htm).

Comment: No, it is not all that remains. It is all that remains in the Roman Liturgy. In the Liturgy of St. Basil and of St. John Chrysostom, if the Bishop is present, there are also the phrases, είς πολλά έτη δέσποτα & άγιος ο Θεός, άγιος ισχυρός, άγιος αθάνατος ελέησον ημάς sung even when the language of the Liturgy is Slavonic. This is a holdover from the days when Bishops in Russia were all Greeks, so they were addressed in their own language and spoke to the congregation in their own language.

Comment: @MattJ., interesting. However, the O.P. was asking about the Roman Rite.

Comment: @MattJ. In the Roman Rite, the Trisagion makes an appearance during the Good Friday service. One of the traditional hymns is the “Reproaches,” which features the Trisagion in Greek and Latin.

Comment: @Wtrmute It is true that the aristocracy would go to Athens to learn classical Greek, but the immigrant poor in Rome were commonly from Greek-speaking areas (e.g., the south of Italy, a.k.a Magna Graecia).

Comment: @Wtrmute There are tons of inscriptions in Greek here in Rome—most of them rather bad quality, which is a good indication that they are from un-learned persons.

Comment: @Wtrmute I never affirmed that there were *few* speakers of Vulgar Latin, just that Greek was the first language of most of poor. Also, I mentioned that Latin eventually took over by about the third century A.D. (As for Modern Italian, that is a different story, since it was imposed on Italy by the government after the unification. Griko used to be much more common in the south of Italy than it is now.)

Comment: @Wtrmute To give you an idea of how pervasive Greek was and is in southern Italy: Cumae was a Greek colony hundreds of years BC.  Neopolis (now Naples) was established as a Greek Colony.  The Neopolitan dialect, still spoken in the Campagna region particularly among the older generations, has major Greek influence in it ... which makes historical sense.  When I was last in Italy about 20 years ago, it was brought to our attention that there are at least 30 active dialects in use in various areas, even though school Italian is the common tongue and what is taught.

Comment: @Wtrmute According to the source I added, (1) most poor people were bilingual, but they were more comfortable with Greek—it is sort of like the situation of the Italian dialects nowadays, only with less advance of the dominant language; (2) Latin remained the language of the state, of the army, and of the surrounding areas outside Rome. Finally, Koine Greek was not the “language of prestige;” it would have had about the respectability of Cockney English. (For any further discussion, I suggest we take it to chat.)

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex: No, I'm fine. I think these sources are enough; I'll remove my previous comments to avoid cluttering up the page, as well.